# Scattering of Light by Pure Water

Tags: optics, water, scattering

I'm looking for a quantitative (and accessible) description on the scattering of NIR light (850 nm) by *pure* water. More specifically, I want to find how much of the incident 850 nm light beam is scattered onto a given direction per meter of pure water.

I found that two processes, the Rayleigh scattering and the Raman scattering, seem to be relevant. I found a formula for the Rayleigh scattering here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering), but I don't know what to use for the radius of the particle (*d*). And though I made some research, I don't quite understand about Raman scattering. A pointer to the relevant info would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: In pure water, the only scatterers could be water molecules.  I suspect the scattering cross-section at that wavelength will be close to zero.

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide (a pointer to) a quantitative description, especially for the Raman scattering?